# I didn't save/download DS-160. How to retrieve my application after 30 days?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas

I started a DS-160 application. It was saved online but not downloaded/saved on my local drive. When I try to retrieve that now, it could not find the file with the confirmation number.

I realize it's been more than 30 days and I only have to upload the file and retrieve but I don't have the file to upload. I have scheduled a visa appointment on this confirmation number. So are there any alternatives to retrieve my DS-160? Any contact or email information where I can reach them? I would highly appreciate it if someone can help me on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There's another valid way - fill out a second DS-160.

There are others online with the same issue, and [one called the US Embassy to check](http://www.visajourney.com/forums/topic/466215-lost-ds-160-application-id/):

> I called the London Embassy to confirm that filling out another DS-160
>   wouldn't produce any problems, and they said that there is no way to
>   retrieve an application ID and that filling out another DS-160 is the
>   only solution. They also said that it would be the same if I had made
>   a mistake on my application and needed to fill it out again and I had
>   forgot my ID.

Comment: Do you need to pay the interview fee again?

Comment: @user13267 I don't know - would presume it's only one interview per application so probably not, but I can't answer definitively. Might be worth asking as a separate question!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I spoke to the US Embassy helpline. They advised that there is no problem and I should fill up a new DS 160 application. Thereafter Ilog-in to my US Visa application site and after logging-in click on the 'Update Profile' link and update my new DS 160 application number and click 'Save'. Thereafter, on the dashboard of the same site, click on "Appointment Confirmation"... you will now see the new DS-160 number updated there with same appointment date and time as has been booked by you previously. It does not affect your already booked visa appointment date and time. I tried it and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can call up US Embassy helpline(based on region), They will be able to help you out. Basically, you will have to do a new DS-160 and update that information in your appointment page. If you face any issues doing it, US Embassy helpline should be able to help you out. 
It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I booked a visa appointment with my DS-160 Appointment ID before I submitted DS-160, I tried to retrieve my DS-160 and submit just 5 days before the date of my visa appointment but I got the same error "file isn't found with the confirmation number" as it has been 45 days since I saved the application. I panicked as I might not get another appointment immediately, many people still think that they can't change DS-160 Appointment number that they used to book Visa appointment, but all you have to do is fill a new DS-160 and submit that, go to ustraveldocs.com and click on update profile, then submit your new DS-160 number there. You will still have your original appointment and make sure to take a printout of your new appointment confirmation with the new DS-160 Application ID on it.

You have 30 days to return to a partially completed DS-160 so don't wait too long to submit your DS-160.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. I didn't save to my pc hard drive and didn't login after 30 days. I got the "no matching data found" when i tried to complete my form.
I had to create a new DS 160 application number.  Then i updated my profile on my account for monitoring visa appointment with the new application ID and i got an instant email for same visa interview date with the new DS application ID on the barcode.